# Relational Algebra equivalent of SQL "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Is there a relational algebra equivalent of the SQL expression `NOT IN`?

For example if I have the relation:

```
A1  |  A2
----------
x   |  y
a   |  b
y   |  x
```

I want to remove all tuples in the relation for which A1 is in A2. In SQL I might query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    R
WHERE
    R.A1 NOT IN
        (
        SELECT
            A2
        FROM
            R
        )
/
```

What is really stumping me is how to subquery inside the relational algebra selection operator, is this possible?:

σ<sub>some subquery here</sub>R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In relational algebra, you can do this using a carthesian product.  Something like:

R - ρ<sub>a1,a2</sub>(π<sub>a11,a21</sub>(σ<sub>A11 = A22</sub>(ρ<sub>a11,a21</sub>(R) x ρ<sub>a12, a22</sub>(R))))

- rename the columns of R, f.e. from a1 to a11 (left hand) and a12 (right hand)
- take the cross product of the R's with renamed columns
- select rows where a11 equals a22
- project out a12 and a22 and keep a11 and a21
- rename to a1 and a2

That gives you the rows that were matched.  Subtract this from R to find the rows that where not matched.

Comment: can you please explain how this works... and maybe expand the ellipsis dots. I am having trouble understanding the result of the cross product, there are only two fields in R so how can you put the pi operator on it with more than two arguments?

Comment: If there are only two columns you can omit the ellipsis dots.  The answer also used PI where it should have used RHO, not sure if that was in the edit or the original answer.

Answer (score 5):

The opening question is sending us down the wrong thinking. It should be:

Is there a relational algebra equivalent of the SQL expression `R WHERE ... [NOT] IN S`?

(That is, the answer is some operation between two relations, *not* some sort of filter.)

The answer is Yes, it is (Natural) `JOIN` aka the bowtie operator `⋈`.

To see why, let's first tidy up the SQL solution given. As shown, it's looking for attribute `A1 NOT IN` a relation with single attribute `A2`. That's really a mis-match in attribute names. SQL also allows `NOT` inside the where condition. This SQL makes the logical structure clearer:

```
SELECT * FROM R
WHERE NOT (A1 IN (SELECT A2 AS A1 FROM R) )
```

Now we can see a projection and a rename. (The surrounding `NOT` we can implement as set MINUS, as per the first answer.) So the equivalent RA is:

`R - (R ⋈ ρ`<sub>A1⁄A2</sub>`(π`<sub>A2</sub>`(R)))`

For interest, the Tutorial D is:

```
R MINUS (R JOIN (R {A2} RENAME A2 AS A1))
```

In the way the question is put, there's a hangover from SQL thinking. SQL's `WHERE` forces you into row-level 'mode'. This is contra Codd's rule 7 requiring set-at-a-time operators.

In general, SQL's `WHERE` and RA's `σ` with their row-level filters can be more succinctly implemented as (Natural) `JOIN` with set-at-a-time logic. (For example, this is what Date & Darwen do in their ***A*** algebra.)

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to a more general question:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    R
WHERE
    R.A1 NOT IN
        (
        SELECT
            A2
        FROM
            S
        );
```

The answer is:

```
R-R "bowtie" [R.A1=S.A2] ("pi" [A2] S )
```